# how to perform scroll in appium using java for iOS

Tags: javascript, java, scroll, appium

I was trying to perform scroll down action in an IOS mobile app using java. There is one javascript line to perform the scroll down action. this is the code I wrote.

```
HashMap<String,Object> params= new HashMap<>();
    params.put("direction", "down");
params.put("name", "Tap here to add promotions by promo code"); 
driver.executeScript("mobile:scroll" , params);
```

this is the error I'm receiving

'Tap here to add promotions by promo code' identifier didn't match any elements

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("YourID"));
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("direction", "down");
    params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement)ele).getId());
    driver.executeScript("mobile:scroll", params);
```

Try this to scroll into a specific element